# converting HQL (hibernate query language) to oracle query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I wnat to Convert HQL query to pure Oracle Query ?

Is there any translators for this.

Ex :

**from Table1** --> Table1 is Entity class for Table

covert it as

**select * from Table**

Thanks in advane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply turn on SQL logging in Hibernate and look at the queries it generates. Specifically, set this property:

```
hibernate.show_sql=true
```

**EDIT**: If stdout isn't available to you based on the way you start your server, then you'll want to change the hibernate logging configuration to print SQL debug logs. Add this line to your log4j properties file.

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Comment: You can also set logging level for `org.hibernate.SQL` to DEBUG.

Comment: thanks, if i added this in hibernate.cfg after that i ran unit tests still its not printing the logs.

Comment: How are you starting your server? If stdout is not available to you, you'll not see the logs. In which case @Piotr's idea of setting the hibernate logging level to debug for sqls would help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use various loggers.

```
<!-- Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed -->
<logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all  JDBC parameters -->
<logger name="org.hibernate.type" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all  second level cache activity -->
<logger name="org.hibernate.cache" level="debug" />
<!-- Log all  transaction related activity -->
<logger name="org.hibernate.transaction" level="debug" />
<!-- Log everything -->
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="debug" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, the `hibernate.show_sql` property for hibernate enables logging the SQL queries Hibernate executes.

For interactive querying, there are Hibernate console plugins for both [Eclipse](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html) and [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-hibernate-console.html) that will let you enter HQL queries and execute them.

Note, this is a useful technique to know if you need to perform optimization of HQL queries (ie, you want to see if your HQL query is being run using the appropriate indexes).